# Facebook log in - auto refresh page

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-like, refresh

I have a problem. When somebody is not logged in facebook and "likes" with the facebook plugin, he is asked to log in facebook. He does it and he has to click on "like" again.

I would like in this situation, just after the guy has logged in to auto-refresh my page (for updating other infos). Is there a way to do that ? Should I use a kind of listener of FB loggin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, I think no - if the login was processed by your own app using the Javascript SDK  you could detect the login (which is a necessary part of the login flow) and put something in your login-handling code to refresh the Like buttons so that when they refresh they're aware the user has logged in.

In the case where the user triggers the login via the like button itself, I don't think there's any way to detect this event